# How can I have a variable binding prefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple partial view that I add in a page using Ajax. I started using using prefixes to avoid name conflicts between the partial views.

In the View or Controller, I set the prefix:

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "MyPartialPrefix";
```

In the Views, I use `@Html.EditorFor` when using the default template or `@Html.IdFor` and `@Html.NameFor` to get the right name and id. When I need an Id for something that isn't in the model (a div that I need to access with javascript for example), I use `@Html.Id("SomeRandomElement")`.

This solution worked perfectly until I decided that I need to use the same partial view more than once. My natural reflex was to turn the static prefix into a randomly generated GUID. However, some (most) of the partial views have forms, which means they end up being sent to a controller action that has to bind the model. With a static prefix, I could use `[Bind(Prefix = "MyPartialPrefix")]`, but if I switch to GUIDs, I need to find that prefix at runtime. I'm not sure where and how this should be done.

My idea was to make a custom ModelBinder that would check for a field called "ModelPrefix" sent with the request and set it as the binding prefix. I got to the point where I have my prefix in a variable in my custom model binder, but I don't know what to do with it. There doesn't see to have a "Prefix" field in the binding context like I originally expected. I've been looking in ASP.NET MVC source to find how the BindAttribute's prefix is handle and I'm getting deeper and deeper in the code until I don't even know what I'm looking at anymore.

```
public class PrefixModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var prefix = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("prefix");
        // What do I do at this point?
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```